# How to run generator in parallel in python

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing, generator, keras, yield

Similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022503/how-to-run-generator-code-in-parallel) i am seeking a way to run a generator of similar structure parallel.

```
def generator():
    while True:
        # do slow calculation
        yield x
```

It is a generator i am running for `fit_generator` in keras in which it would be highly desirable to run both in parallel to make things more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

by [keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator), the generator runs parallel by default